# Getting null Set value in Post request from spring form

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-form

i am trying to get question and it's multiple options. i am getting successfully Question but its options getting null.

```html
<c:forEach begin="0" end="${optionsCount}"  varStatus="loop">

       <form:input path="options[${loop.index}].mcq"/>                              

</c:forEach>
```

```java
public class OnlineTestQuestionBean {

    private String optionsCount;

    private Long questionId;

    private String question;

    private Set<QuestionOptionBean> options;

   //setter getter
}

public class QuestionOptionBean {

    private Long optionId;
    private String mcq;

          //setter getter
}
```

following is Controller Code :-

```java
@Controller
public class OnlineTestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/savequestion", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addQuestion(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("OnlineTestQuestionBean", onlineTestQuestionBean);


        return "addquestion";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/savequestion", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveQuestion(@ModelAttribute("OnlineTestQuestionBean")OnlineTestQuestionBean onlineTestQuestionBean, Model model) {

        return null;
    }

}
```

Following is Spring Form code :-

```html
<c:forEach begin="0" end="${optionsCount}"  varStatus="loop">

       <form:input path="options[${loop.index}].mcq"/>                              

</c:forEach>
```

When i submit that time i get "Cannot get element with index 0 from Set of size 0, accessed using property path" this Exception,

suppose i used following code i get null set value.

```html
<input type="text" path="options.mcq"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following in the form :

```
<c:forEach 
    <c:forEach items="${options}" var="option">
    <form:input path="option.mcq"/>                              
</c:forEach>
```